# React Router v4: Component and Children in the same route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am a beginner with react and have upgraded a base project to react router v4. The app seems to be working fine, but I am always getting the following warning:

**Warning: You should not use <Route component> and <Route children> in the same route; <Route children> will be ignored**

This is my app (leaving some imports out for readability):

**index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
        <BrowserRouter>{routes}</BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
    , document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**routes.js:**

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';


export default (
    <Main>
      <Route path="/topics/create" component={CreateTopicView}> </Route>
      <Route path="/topics/search" component={SearchTopicsView}> </Route>
      <Route path="/topics/manage" component={ManageTopicsView}> </Route>
      <Route path="/moderation/pre" component={ModerationPreView}> </Route>
      <Route path="/moderation/post" component={ModerationPostView}></Route>
      <Route path="/dashboard" component={DashboardView}> </Route>
      <Route exact={true} path="/" component={DashboardView}> </Route>
    </Main>
);
```

**main.js:**

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'


class Main extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        match: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        location: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
      }

    render() {
        let wrapperClass = "gray-bg " + this.props.location.pathname;
        return (
            <div id="wrapper">
                <Progress />
                <Navigation location={this.props.location}/>

                <div id="page-wrapper" className={wrapperClass}>

                    <TopHeader />

                    {this.props.children}

                    <Footer />

                </div>

            </div>

        )
    }
}


export default withRouter(Main)
```

The idea is that most components in the `Main` component (e.g. the `Navbar`) should always be loaded, also the `Navbar` needs to know the current path so it can display the current selection.

Then between the `TopHeader` and `Footer` the variable content should be shown based on the path.

What am I doing wrong, how can I solve the warning about `Route Component` and `Route Children` in the same path?

Comment: Thats because you have space between your Routes. which behave as a children and routes in v4 are not suppose to have children

`<Route path="/topics/create" component={CreateTopicView}>{/* you have space here */}</Route>`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Wow that fixed it thanks!

Comment: @Mustika You should post this as an answer and accept it so others can see that your problem was solved,.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Shubham Khatri mentioned in the comment, the warning was caused by a space I had after the route opening tag:

> Thats because you have space between your Routes. which behave as a
>   children and routes in v4 are not suppose to have children <Route
>   path="/topics/create" component={CreateTopicView}>{/* you have space
>   here */}</Route>

Changing the Route definitions to

```
<Route path="/topics/create" component={CreateTopicView}></Route>
```

or

```
<Route path="/topics/create" component={CreateTopicView} />
```

fixed the warning